# Component affecting if/else outcome in svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a strange situation in svelte 3 where adding a sub-component in the markup is affecting the outcome of if/else blocks. Given this markup, why would the first **htmlColumns.includes** output **TRUE!!!** but the second else if with same exact condition never outputs **AGAIN!!!**?

```
{#each columns as column}
    {#if htmlColumns.includes(column)}
        <td>TRUE!!!</td>
    {/if}
    {#if computedColumns[column] }
        <td><span>{row['_' + column]}</span></td>
    {:else if htmlColumns.includes(column)}
        <td>AGAIN!!!</td>
    {:else}
        <td class="data-grid-cell-editor">
            <CellEditor table={table} references={references[column]} displayValue={row['_' + column]} value={row[column]} field={column} record={row} />
        </td>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

[image]

Where it gets really confusing is if I remove my custom **CellEditor** component from the final else block, the if/else logic behaves as expected outputting AGAIN!!!:

```
{#each columns as column}
    {#if htmlColumns.includes(column)}
        <td>TRUE!!!</td>
    {/if}
    {#if computedColumns[column] }
        <td><span>{row['_' + column]}</span></td>
    {:else if htmlColumns.includes(column)}
        <td>AGAIN!!!</td>
    {:else}
        <td>CRAZY!!!</td>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

[image]

How can the CellEditor component be affecting the outcome of the if/else logic block? I have stripped the CellEditor component down to just a single div with no script and it still affects it the same way.

Comment: Why is this line different in the second snippet: `{#if computedColumns && computedColumns[column] }`? Are you sure they don't all pass in the `computedColumns[column]` condition in the first case? Could you do something like styling your `span`s with 30px neon pink borders to prove it?

Comment: Updated and tested with same result. All I have to do is remove the CellEditor component and it changes the logic flow.

Comment: OK then there might be a bug in the framework (or I'm missing something too). Can you reproduce that in a REPL or some code you can share?

Comment: Here's a REPL with minimal data - but it works as expected. Maybe it helps to track down the issue with your real implementation: https://svelte.dev/repl/09d5dc7bf9cb4512a8e0213e8c083ecd?version=3.19.1

Comment: Thank you for the REPL. I will keep testing and see if I can isolate it. I can only assume it's something on my end that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4536#issuecomment-598647689

Comment: On its way to be fixed real soon, apparently: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/4558

Comment: Ah, that's it! Thank you. Thought I was going crazy there for a minute.

Comment: The fix has been released with Svelte 3.20.0. Do you still have the issue with your specific case?

Comment: The update to 3.20.0 has fixed it for me